# NUnit - UpdateModel issue: NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit

I have problem with testing classes, which using UpdateModel() method.
I get System.NullReferenceException.
I use NUnit.
This is my method from HomeController:

```
    public ActionResult ProjectsEdit(Projects model)
    {
        var projects = db.Projects.First();
        projects.Content = model.Content;
        UpdateModel(projects);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Projects");            
    }
```

Here is test class:

```
    [Test]
    public void ProjectsEditPostTest()
    {
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
        //var httpContext = new FakeHttpContext("Edit");
        FormCollection formParameters = new FormCollection();
        ControllerContext controllerContext =
        MockRepository.GenerateStub<ControllerContext>(httpContext,
                                                            routeData,
                                                            controller);
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

        // Act
        string newContent = "new content";
        Projects projects = new Projects { ID = 1, Content = newContent };
        controller.ProjectsEdit(projects);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(newContent, controller.db.Projects.First().Content);            
    }
```

What should I do to make it works?

Comment: what line of code throws the exception?

Comment: UpdateModel(projects); //from HomeController
and
controller.ProjectsEdit(projects); //from HomeControllerTest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following line in the Assert phase:

```
controller.ValueProvider = formParameters.ToValueProvider();
```

It assigns a value provider to the controller on which the `UpdateModel` method relies. This value provider is associated to the FormCollection variable you have defined and which allows you to pass some values.

You may also check a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896695/mvcontrib-mvc3-testhelper-updatemodel-nullreferenceexceuption-during-unit-test/4896795#4896795) which uses [MvcContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) to simplify the Arrange phase.

Comment: @jj09, it did work form me when I tested the code. Maybe you would like to show what exactly you have tried?

Comment: It's works when I added this line before //Act! Thank you for help!